# Marklogic|NodeJS API facet query by geolocation

Tags: node.js, marklogic

So, I have a structure like

```
{
  city: "City",
  geolocation:
    {
      lat: 55,
      lng:55
    }
}
```

and I want do to a count by geolocation where I return the city too but I cannot get the facet by geolocation to work. I created a geospatial element index, geospatial element pair index and for the query I tried the following:

```
qb.facet("count", qb.property("geolocation"))

qb.facet("count", qb.geoPropertyPair("geolocation", "lat", "lng"))

qb.facet("count", qb.geoProperty("geolocation"))

qb.facet("count", qb.geoElement("geolocation"))
```

and with all of these my facet query is empty or inexistent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce the bug. While geospatial queries over JSON documents work, geospatial facets over JSON documents are not working in the REST API.

The only workaround I can see is to write a custom constraint that executes cts:geospatial-boxes() in XQuery or cts.geospatialBoxes() in JavaScript, install the module on the server, and refer to the custom constraint in the query.  For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750

http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/config.query.custom.html

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.box

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:box

Comment: The REST API fix should be in 8.0-4